# Vim rails.vim plugin doesn't seem to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, rails.vim

I've installed rails.vim plugin. Running `:Rails!` 
command shows: *rails.vim 4.3*. But when I try to run `:Rails myapp` it opens command line (cmd.exe) that shows:

`C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c rails myapp`. Bunch of rails help comes up and nothing happens. There is have to be something I'm missing.

I use gvim v7.3. rails 3.0.5.

My _vimrc has only this:

```
set nocompatible
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:Rails myapp` is used to create a new rail project in the current working directory by calling the "rails" command.

I think the issue is that "rails myapp" is the syntax fro pre-3.0, and it is now "**rails new myapp**".

So it seems your Rails.vim is not up to date. (or Rails.vim is broken for RoR > 3.0 ?)

Create your app directly from the console, and use Rails.vim to navigate/refactor it. This is the main interest of using Rails.vim

If you are working on a existing project, you just need to open any *.rb file of the project and you should see [Rails] in the status bar.

From there, all Rails vim command should be available like :Rfind, :Redit, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:Rails new projectname` for Rails 3.